# I've deleted my /var/lib/dpkg/status and status old files

Tags: apt, dpkg, system-recovery

I run Deepin, I've been trying to install the necessary compenents to run a LAMP server on my machine for web development. As the title says I've somehow deleted my status files. I'm not sure how, I'm a student with a decent understanding of linux but when I went to apt-get something I was met with a 'bad address' error. On investigating that I discovered the missing status file. I tried to copy the status-old file to a new file named status, but the permissions made it difficult, even in super user mode and I accidentally deleted the status-old file, my own fault. Very frustrating. Anyway, I can't download the necessary files to create a bootable usb etc. to install ubuntu (been meaning to switch) as my apt-get is broken. How can I fix my computer?

Answer (score 0):

There should have been backups at `/var/backups/dpkg.*`.